# Imagenes pasa de horizontal a vertical al colocar encabezado o texto en tabla

Tags: html, css, imagen, tablas

el problema es que tengo ordenadas las imagenes de forma horizontal, se encuentran con un hover, todo perfecto. Pero al momento de intentar agregarle un texto debajo ya sea mediante p o span o h etc. o entre otros que intentado, mis imagenes QUEDAN EN POSICION VERTICAL, la verdad nose pq pasa pero al momento de internar ponerle un titulo o encabezado debajo, pasan de horizontal a vertical. Ayuda porfavor

```html
<table>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<a href="" class="mainmenu" /><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
</tr>
<tr>
<a href="" class="mainmenu" /><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en la sintaxis, primero estás cerrando la etiqueta `<a>` dos veces, esta etiqueta no es selfclosing por ende no debe cerrarse cuando se declara `<a />`. Segundo, la estructura de la tabla debe tener filas y columnas, se te juntaron las filas horizontalmente porque el elemento hijo tiene un `display: inline`, pero en realidad tienes que poner etiquetas de columnas `<td>`. En conclusión debería quedar algo así.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="" class="mainmenu">
<img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20">
</a>
<p>
LOL
</p>
</td>
<td>
<a href="" class="mainmenu"><img title="Overlord" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wmXOMSvGdqE/W1olljMPl8I/AAAAAAAAASE/zcrXBcEDR5Q72zGVf24_41unNrU-fE7DACEwYBhgL/w140-h87-p/HALF_LIFE_3_WALLPAPERS_IN_HD.jpg"  alt="" HSPACE="20"></a>
<p>
LOL
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos Viteri, la verdad  no tengo mucho conocimiento de html, de verdad gracias por la ayuda, me salvaste.